# how to check window.history.back has value in javascript

Tags: javascript, window, back, browser-history

i am creating a page with back button in corner. if the page launched for first back button should hide. if user navigates through page back button should show.

i used the code

`(window.history.length > 1)?$("#back").show():$("#back").hide();`

but my problem is,
`window.history.length`  is keeps increasing.

But my requirement is when there is no page to go back then back button should hide again. how to achieve that?

Comment: is this something you're paginating yourself, e.g. with a `<< < 1 2 3 ... n > >>` type nav system? presumably you'd know which page you're on and would simply hide the appropriate buttons when you're on page 1 or n.

Comment: The history API doesn't provide a way to find out where the current page is in the history list.

Answer (score 1):

you have more problems. what if the user came from google? there would be window history already. What if a user went to your site, then went to google, then came back?

If it's just a nav system as described by @Marc B, it's easy, you know where the user came from and how to get back (don't use the history directly). But if it is a back button no matter what link the user clicks into your site... it gets more complicated. Due to privacy restrictions, you can't access the user's actual URL history (just the length) and you can't access whatever url they are navigating to if you use capture the window.unload event. So you're left with limited options.

One option would be to record the window location on every page load to an array that you keep in either local storage, or a cookie. Then you should use this array to manage your history state rather than relying on window.history. When the user clicks your back button, you just pop off the last url on your site they visited and navigate them there. Keep in mind the first page load will put an item into your history array, so depending on where you check to see if you should show or hide your history button, you'll compare the length of your history array to either 0 or 1.